# Can operating system vulnerabilities affect database security?

Tags: security, operating-system, database

Let's say an operating system is installed on a computer and a DBMS is installed on the same computer. Suppose that the operating system has a security vulnerability. Is there a possibility that the security vulnerability of the OS causes a security vulnerability of the DBMS?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the offtopic question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

absolutely.  If a user can exploit an OS bug to get root access, they can do anything they want.  Steal your database, mess around with things, etc...

That's why its important to always get latest security updates for you servers.  Also, its common practice to keep servers in a de-militarized zone, behind firewalls.  Only the ports that need to be open should be open.

Comment: Thank you. But what happens if an attacker has found a technique for sending packets through the firewall to the DMZ without the packets being checked. Suppose the attacker doesn't know the internal addresses of hosts in the DMZ. Can the attacker arrange for a packet to be sent to the www server in the DMZ without the firewall checking the packet? (I'm thinking about email spoofing and email forgery)

Comment: Lajos, that is a great question, and beyond me.  Ask in the appropriate stack site http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Thank you again, hvgotcodes, I'm sorry I've posted off-topic. Also, I would like to accept your answer, but I don't have the possibility, because the question is closed as off-topic.

Comment: no worries.  Just upvote in that case ;)

Comment: I have already upvoted your answer in the moment I've seen it.